# How to implement hover over hints for iPhone app?

Tags: iphone

I have an iPhone app that I would like to add some help hints to. I've seen this in other apps where you might hover over a text field or button and a popup appears indicating to the user what is supposed to be entered or done for that field or button.

Can anyone provide any suggestions or examples?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iPhones don't have that kind of thing because you can't detect when somebody is hovering their finger over the screen, only when you touch it.

If you're looking for ways to explain things to the user, take a look at one of the design patterns libraries, such as [the edu walkthroughs on Mobile UI Patterns](http://mobile-patterns.com/edu).

Comment: I guess one way to do it would be to detect touches when the user taps, then use an alertview to tell them what to do.